# iOS: NSMutableArray is empty

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, nsmutablearray

```
for (XMLProductView *pV in entries) {
        NSString *test = pV.appName;
        [allTableData addObject:test];

        NSLog(@"Entries: %@", allTableData);
    }
```

In my `NSString *test` I get all results. Why does the `NSMutableArray` 'allTableData' show up `Null`?

Comment: Has it definitely been alloc'd? Are you using ARC?

Comment: Most probably you never allocated it.  Objective-C will happily ignore calls to a function using a null pointer, so you can run for 100 lines with the pointer null before you discover a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is hard to say because you added just a few information, but probably you are not allocating it correctly.

Try to add it before your for:

```
allTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (XMLProductView *pV in entries) {
    NSString *test = pV.appName;
    [allTableData addObject:test];
}
NSLog(@"Entries: %@", allTableData);
```

--

**Edit**

I edited the code to try to make it clear.

Comment: Ok when I add this, I'm getting a `SIGABRT` here: `pV = [allTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: That is probably because `indexPath.row` is greater than the `-length` of the array.

Comment: @SaschaWieland are you putting this alloc/init inside the loop? If so don't, put it before the loop starts.